# unbind/turn off a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day all, I'm trying to make a jquery game where a group of enemy will spawn after a group of enemy gets destroyed. I'm calling `alien_cruiser()` function & unbinding `minion_roulette()` function after `minion_roulette_counter` gets 0. But every time I run, function does not get unbind & after counter gets 0 both type of enemies show. I want to run them one by one. Here are the codes:

```
var sound = new Audio("sounds//dishoom.ogg");
var score = 0;
var minion_roulette_life = 10;
var cruiser_life = 20;
var minion_roulette_counter = 3;
var cruiser_counter = 3;

function processBullet() {
$(".projectile").each(function() {
    var maxTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var breakable1 = $(this).collision("#minion-roulette");
    var breakable2 = $(this).collision("#cruiser");
    $(this).css("top", maxTop - 25);

    if (breakable1.length != 0 || breakable2.length != 0) {
        $(this).remove();
    }

    if (maxTop <= 35) {
        $(this).remove();
    }

    if (breakable1.length != 0) {
        --minion_roulette_life;
        if (minion_roulette_life == 0) {
            sound.play();
            breakable1.remove();
            minion_roulette(true);
            minion_roulette_counter--;
            $("#score").html(++score);
            minion_roulette_life = 10;
        }
    }

    //This is the place where it checks if counter is 0 or not

    if (minion_roulette_counter == 0) {
        $('#content').unbind(function() {
            minion_roulette(false)
        });
        alien_cruiser(false);
        minion_roulette_counter = -1;
    }

    if (breakable2.length != 0) {
        --cruiser_life;
        if (cruiser_life == 0) {
            sound.play();
            breakable2.remove();
            alien_cruiser(true);
            $("#score").html(++score);
            cruiser_life = 20;
        }
    }
});
}
```

Am I doing any wrong here? Please I need a solution badly. Tnx.

Comment: can you show us the code where you bind the function? You typically unbind the type of event, ie if you do `$(this).bind('click', someFunction);` you would do `$(this).unbind('click');` (to unbind ALL click events) or `$(this).unbind('click', someFunction);` to unbind the specific click event that runs that specific function.

Comment: Also, the better syntax is to use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` and `.off()` instead of `.unbind()` if you're using a relatively recent version of jQuery

Comment: @Derek, I didn't bind the function to any click event. I thought `.unbind()` is used to turn off the function. I just want to turn off a function & then turn on another function after counter gets 0.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you could use a conditional statement to determine which function to call. 
For example:

```
if (minion_roulette_counter == 0) {
   alien_cruiser();
}
else {
  minion_roulette();
}
```

Binding and unbinding doesn't 'turn off' a function, unfortunately. To quote MDN:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

– [MDN: 'Bind'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)